# -C option is ignored when calling tar via PHP

Tags: php, exec, tar

If I run my PHP file from the shell, then the tar command extracts to the directory I am in, rather than the one I specified using -C

My command is

```
passthru("tar xvf $file $tarfile/application $tarfile/application_detail $tarfile/application_device_type $tarfile/genre_application -C /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/fred");
```

How can I have it extract the specific files to the specified destination directory?

The filename is filename.tgz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you have:

```
tar xvf tarfile paths... -C target
```

Change the order of the arguments to:

```
tar xvf tarfile -C target paths...
```